# Mapping client code to source code is not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications, source-maps

I am creating a simple web app using a Google Apps Script, I want to add the client code to the source code so that I can use it for debugging if I have errors. etc

**UPDATE: STRUCTURE OF MY CODE in editor**

[image]

Here is my codes.

code.gs

```
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
  .evaluate()
  .setTitle('APP')
}
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <?!= include('importsJs'); ?>
  <?!= include('other/employee/scripts'); ?>
  <?!= include('other/jobs/scripts'); ?>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

I have learned on the Internet about mapping client code to source code in dev tools, I just need to add `//# sourceURL = filename.js`

employees html file (other/employee/scripts) looks like this

```html
<script>
var employees = [{ name: 'Charlie', position: 'Sales' }];

console.log(employees)

//# sourceURL=employee.js
</script>
```

and jobs html file (other/jobs/scripts) looks like this

```html
<script>
var employees = [{ name: 'Charlie', position: 'Sales' }];

console.log(employees)

//# sourceURL=employee.js
</script>
```

Here is the source code in the editor [demo](https://script.google.com/u/0/home/projects/1143wR717G3R_3aIQAA2haWsZij0AobBeI3rS8WgwYt9g3WypA6EgQiw7/edit)

The expected result is when you click usercodepanel it should show me the line of code which give the console log results, for now when you click it's empty :( very bad for debugging

[image]

[Live demo](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwDaRdgdHAH2wYCbc_WcyXTI6moJQRz6dxS60YbHuM/dev)

**NOTE: I am loading JavaScript files dynamically using the doT.js library.**

**UPDATE:** on my local machine, the source code looks like this, am using **clasp** to deploy my project

[source codes](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-darkness-l8dq1u?file=/index.html)

The solution above does not give me what I want, what do I need to do to get the expected results?

Comment: What do you mean by "I am loading JavaScript files dynamically using the doT.js library"? Where does this this library come from? employees and jobs snippets in the question have the same code.  Check that in your project this is not happening and that each file name for source mapping is not used more than one time.

Comment: Where are the scripts of `importsJs` of `include('importsJs')` and `other/employee/scripts` of `include('other/employee/scripts')` and `other/jobs/scripts` of `include('other/jobs/scripts')` in your actual situation?

Comment: The demo links are not shared. Please add a [mcve] directly into the question body.

Comment: What is this `other/employee/scripts` I don't think the script editor supports subdirectories.

Comment: @Cooper its just an html file with script inside, check the updated qn

Comment: @Rubén I am loading my all js file using doT.js library , check my updated question

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with that library. The snippets looks the same. The links looks that not require acces, but own of them requires to verify my account. I don't have time now for this. I will look again to this this night.

Comment: @Rubén here is the full source : https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-dream-0387z4 just add this project to editor the same as screen short provided

Comment: My understanding is that all of the html files must be created from the files section of the script editor.  They can't be in just any folder of your choosing

Comment: @Cooper  the format I have is when your developing on a local machine using a clasp, in my screenshot, you can see the format that works fine and its production format

Comment: @Rubén did you have time to check the issue as you promised ? due to complex of the problem I am awarding 500 for a working solution to the problem

Comment: @TheDeadMan I'm sorry. I haven't. I appreciate the effort you are doing on offering the bounty. IMO it's better to fix address issues mentioned in comments before offering a bounty, i.e. fix the repeated code snippet, add a [mcve].

Comment: Previously I have mentione that I'm not familiar with doT.js. I used source code mapping in a project that become too complex to apps script (a lot of include scriptlets, multiple apps script libraries) ... the source code mapping worked perfectly without using javascript libraries other than Boostrap for handling the front-end look and feel. Anyway, I'm sorry, I can't look at your links at this time, not sure if I will be able to do it this week.

Comment: @Rubén OK. no worries, I think Denis is so close to what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are encountering is that, upon deployment, App Script removes all static comments in your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript in order to optimize your site. But truthfully, it does this too aggressively and naively, removing any appearance of "// ..." in the code, even if it's located inside a template string, where it's actually valid.

As a result, there is no simple toggle to just make it work, but there is a very hacky workaround. Do not include "//" statically in your code, instead, dynamically insert it with your scripts into the HTML as the page loads. To do so, we can write a helper function in App Script called `importScript()` that outputs a script that itself injects a script with the sourceURL and your code into the HTML.

Here is the implementation of `importScript()`:

```js
// in Code.gs
function includeFile(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function stripScriptTags(script) {
  const OPEN_TAG = "<script>",
        CLOSE_TAG = "</script>",
        start = script.indexOf(OPEN_TAG),
        end = script.lastIndexOf(CLOSE_TAG);
  if (start === -1 || end === -1) throw new Error("Encountered malformed script");
  return script.slice(start + OPEN_TAG.length, end).trim();
}

function includeScript(filename, sourceURL) {
  const scriptContent = stripScriptTags(includeFile(filename));
  const escapedScriptStr = scriptContent.replace(/[`$]/g, '\\$&');

  return `
    <script>
      var newScript = document.createElement("script");
      newScript.text = "!!# sourceURL=${sourceURL}".replaceAll("!","/"); 
      newScript.text += "\\n" + \`${escapedScriptStr}\`;
      document.currentScript.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", newScript);
    </script>
  `;
}
```

To use it, simply update your Index.html to call `includeScript()` with the your scripts' filenames and the source URLs you want to use:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <?!= includeScript('other/jobs/scripts', 'jobs.js'); ?>
    <?!= includeScript('other/employee/scripts', 'employee.js'); ?>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then just deploy your App Script, and now you should see the following in the console:
[image]

[Here is my own App Script that demos it working with `sourceURL`.](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby5EupAYBcTrB1j3aFjTuxPTVvhJJOthvlr7myMY3z69SBytKkEJ70HEU0jBkk20U3xpQ/exec)

**NOTE: The method above works if the imported scripts only contain a single script tag. Otherwise, all other HTML in the file gets truncated.**

However, here is a more complicated version of `importScripts()` which works with arbitrary HTML (multiple tags) in the files, and a [demo](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxUM6AafuIPhOPx1vYB8WfCMjwHgTLSx7x28TtymzcKaL3A1gzvIwsmjXCxzryHERR43g/exec):

```js
function includeScript(filename, sourceURL) {
  scriptContent = includeFile(filename)
    .replace(/<script>/g, '<script data-to-clone>')
    .replace(/<\/script>/g, '<\\/script>')
    .replace(/[`$]/g, '\\$&').trim();

  return `
    <script>
      document.currentScript.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", \`${scriptContent}\`);
    </script>
    <script>
      var _temp = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("script[data-to-clone]"));
      _temp.reverse();
      _temp.forEach((scriptClone) => {
        scriptClone.removeAttribute("data-to-clone");

        const newScript = document.createElement("script");
        newScript.text = "/" + "/# sourceURL=${sourceURL}";
        newScript.text += "\\n" + scriptClone.text.trim();
        document.currentScript.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", newScript);

        scriptClone.setAttribute("data-is-cloned", "");
      });
    </script>
  `;
}
```

Comment: Hi Denis your solution works for plain js, but my structure can't be changed now to use plain js instead of <script> inside the HTML file, our project allows developers to change things on the editor directly with plain js will be tough and not allowed, so can you change your solution so that I can be able to use script inside of HTML instead of plain js?  thank you so much for this one

Comment: I updated the code to work with <script> inside the HTML files by stripping it from the text. As a result, it only works if those files contain **only** a single script tag. All the other HTML in those files is truncated. There may be a better solution using `insertAdjacentHTML()`,  but I kept running into parsing issues.

Comment: Your are right all file that I need to use this feature has just one script tag, the importsJs.html file just import all other required 3rd part libraries like jquery, which I can use includeFile function to load it to the dom and the rest of the script files to use includeScript function , in all you have done a wonderful job , your solution works perfect , thank you a lot I spend two days to solve this

Comment: I got it to work with arbitrary HTML (multiple tags), in case you need it in Edit 3. But this took quite some effort to figure out, so I hope this means I earned that bounty 

Comment: Yes absolutely you have earned the bounty, even chatGPT was not able to solve this, so your job is safe  , you will be rewarded the bounty in 10 hrs due to stackoverflow rules when I tried to award you, I got the message 'You may award your bounty worth 500 reputation in 10 hours'

Comment: While it is still early,...congratulations :)

Comment: Please don't use "append edit notices", instead update your answer organically. Think that post should be helpful to a broad audience. Posts in Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange has a built-in post timeline and revision history. Every time that you edit a post you can add a edit summary, use that to briefly describe the changes. If something is not really relevant for future reader, better to use comments for that or a chatroom.